ASP.net web form project, Problem going into edit mode on a ListView
I have a listView which display data from a SQL table so far so good, also I have a form that enter data into it, in that form there is a dropdown(ID:DDL_code)that is populated from another table. To explain more the table that feed the dropdownlist have 2 columns Code and CodeName, the method to populate the dropdown use:
DDL_code.DataTextField = "CodeName";
DDL_code.DataValueField = "Code";
DDL_code.DataBind(); 

My itemdatabound method is:
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if the item is in edit mode
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem && ListView1.EditIndex == e.Item.DataItemIndex)
    {
        // Find the TextBox controls in edit mode
        TextBox txtStoreNum = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtEditStoreNum");
        TextBox txtStoreName = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtEditStoreName");
        TextBox txtStoreContact = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtEditStoreContact");
        DropDownList DDL_code = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("EditDDL_Code");
        TextBox txtIssue = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtEditIssue");

        // Populate TextBox controls with the current values
        if (txtStoreNum != null)
            txtStoreNum.Text = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)["StoreNum"].ToString();
        if (txtStoreName != null)
            txtStoreName.Text = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)["StoreName"].ToString();
        if (txtStoreContact != null)
            txtStoreContact.Text = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)["StoreContact"].ToString();
        if (DDL_Code != null)
            DDL_Code.SelectedValue = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)["Code"].ToString();
        if (txtIssue != null)
            txtIssue.Text = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)["Issue"].ToString();
    }
}

the markup for DDL_Code and EditDDL_Code
<td>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="EditDDL_Code" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Code") %>'></asp:DropDownList>

</td>


<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_Code" runat="server" placeholder="Trouble Code" TabIndex="4" ToolTip="Choose trouble code" /><br /><br />

The problem is when i press the Edit button i get an error 'EditDDL_Code' System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'EditDDL_code' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value'
Others methods,
protected void ListView1_ItemEditing(object sender, ListViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ListView1_ItemEditing");
            ListView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            BindListViewData();
        }
protected void BindListViewData()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("BindListViewData");
            // Retrieve the logged-in username
            string loggedInUsername = _Default.uName;

            // SQL query to retrieve data for the current user and date
            string query = "SELECT Id, StoreNum, StoreName, StoreContact, CallDate, CallTime, Code, Issue, UserN " +
                           "FROM call_log " +
                           "WHERE UserN = @LoggedInUsername AND CONVERT(date, CallDate) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE())";

            // Fetch data from the database
            DataTable dt = ExecuteQuery(query, loggedInUsername);

            // Bind the retrieved data to the ListView control
            ListView1.DataSource = dt;
            ListView1.DataBind();
        }
private DataTable ExecuteQuery(string query, string loggedInUsername)
        {
            // DataTable to hold the results
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            // Using statement ensures proper disposal of resources
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                // Create SqlCommand with parameter
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    // Add parameters
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoggedInUsername", loggedInUsername);

                    // Open connection and fill DataTable
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
            }

            // Return filled DataTable
            return dt;
        }


I have not used webforms in many years, but I remember with gridview and listview, I had to take in consideration NULL or "" or String.empty.  If this condition is not checked the databind will break.

i am going crazy with this.

If [code] is null, then it not going to be in that list, is it?
So, you need:
        TextBox txtStoreNum = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtEditStoreNum");
        TextBox txtStoreName = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtEditStoreName");
        TextBox txtStoreContact = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtEditStoreContact");
        DropDownList DDL_code = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("EditDDL_Code");
        TextBox txtIssue = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtEditIssue");

        DataRowView gRow = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem);

        txtStoreNum.Text = gRow["StoreNum"].ToString();
        txtStoreName.Text = gRow["StoreName"].ToString();
        txtStoreContact.Text = gRow["StoreContact"].ToString();
        if (gRow["Code"] != null)
            DDL_Code.SelectedValue = gRow["Code"].ToString();
        
        txtIssue.Text = gRow["Issue"].ToString();

StoreName etc. will work fine for nulls, since the .ToString() will convert the null value to a empty string, but for the dropdown list, we can't send it a emtpy string, and we can't set the dropdown list value if the [Code] is null in the data and not yet set.

i think am not even getting there, the error is marked when is trying to DataBind() afterEdit is pressed.
